# Error LNK2019 external

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, lnk2019

I can't quite make sense of the errors i get when trying to get my project to work. 
Can someone maybe point me in the right direction? I am fairly new to C++, so I might be doing something crucially wrong here without being aware of it. 
The errormessages I get are as following:

```
Fehler  6   error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol        ""public: struct Camera __thiscall Scene::getCamera(void)" (?    getCamera@Scene@@QAE?AUCamera@@XZ)" in Funktion ""public: void __thiscall     Renderer::render(void)" (?render@Renderer@@QAEXXZ)". ...\source\renderer.obj     raytracer

Fehler  4   error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: class std::vector<class std::shared_ptr<class Shape>,class std::allocator<class std::shared_ptr<class Shape> > > __thiscall Scene::getShapes(void)const " (?getShapes@Scene@@QBE?AV?$vector@V?$shared_ptr@VShape@@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$shared_ptr@VShape@@@std@@@2@@std@@XZ)" in Funktion ""public: void __thiscall Renderer::render(void)" (?render@Renderer@@QAEXXZ)".    ...source\renderer.obj  raytracer
```

Here is my code:

```
#include "color.hpp"
#include "pixel.hpp"
#include "ppmwriter.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <shape.h>
#include "sdfloader.h"
#include <optional_hit.h>
#include <scene.h>

Renderer::Renderer(Scene const& scene, unsigned w, unsigned h, std::string const& file)
: width_(w)
, height_(h)
, colorbuffer_(w*h, Color(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
, filename_(file)
, ppm_(width_, height_)
, scene_(scene)
{}

void Renderer::render() {

camera_ = scene_.getCamera();
shapes_ = scene_.getShapes();
lights_ = scene_.getLights();

camera_.position = glm::vec3(0, 0, tan((90.0 - camera_.opening_angle / 2.0) * M_PI / 180.0) * (double(width_) / 2.0));
testOutput();

Ray first_ray;
for (unsigned y = 0; y < height_; ++y) {
    for (unsigned x = 0; x < width_; ++x) {
        Pixel p(x, y);

        //first ray is created here
        glm::vec3 poip = glm::vec3(double(x) - double(width_) / 2.0, double(y) - double(height_) / 2.0, 0);
        first_ray.origin = camera_.position;
        first_ray.direction = poip - camera_.position;

        double delta = -1;
        Shape *closest_obj;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < shapes_.size(); ++i) {
            double d = shapes_[i]->intersect(first_ray);
            if (d > 1.0 && (d < delta || delta == -1)) {
                delta = d;
                closest_obj = shapes_[i].get();
            }
        }

        if (delta == -1) {
            p.color = Color(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        } else {
            glm::vec3 hit_point = first_ray.origin + (float) delta * first_ray.direction;
            p.color = calculateColor(closest_obj, hit_point, first_ray);
        }

        // draw pixel
        write(p);
    }
}
ppm_.save(filename_);
}

void Renderer::write(Pixel const& p)
{
 // flip pixels, because of opengl glDrawPixels
size_t buf_pos = (width_*p.y + p.x);
if (buf_pos >= colorbuffer_.size() || (int)buf_pos < 0) {
std::cerr << "Fatal Error Renderer::write(Pixel p) : "
  << "pixel out of ppm_ : "
  << (int)p.x << "," << (int)p.y
  << std::endl;
} else {
 colorbuffer_[buf_pos] = p.color;
 }

ppm_.write(p);
}

/*Optional_hit Renderer::intersect(Ray const& ray) const{
Optional_hit o;
    Optional_hit temp;
    std::vector<float> hits;*/

  void Renderer::testOutput() {
    std::cout << "Objects in scene:" << std::endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < shapes_.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << "Object names: " << shapes_[i]->getName() << std::endl;
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < lights_.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << "Lightsource: " << lights_[i].getName() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Camera used: " << camera_.name << " | Focal Length: " <<      camera_.position.z << std::endl;
}
Color Renderer::calculateColor(const Shape* hit_obj, glm::vec3 const&     hit_point, Ray const& first_ray) {
Color final_color = Color(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < lights_.size(); ++i) {

    glm::vec3 n = hit_obj->getNormalAt(hit_point);
    glm::vec3 l = lights_[i].getPosition() - hit_point;

    Ray sec_ray = Ray(hit_point, l);

    Color diffuse_light;
    Color specular_light;
    if (!Shadow(sec_ray) && glm::dot(glm::normalize(n), glm::normalize(l)) > 0) {

        Color Ip = lights_[i].getLD();
        Color kd = hit_obj->getMaterial().getKD();
        diffuse_light = (Ip * kd * glm::dot(glm::normalize(n), glm::normalize(l)));

        glm::vec3 r = 2 * glm::dot(glm::normalize(n), glm::normalize(l)) * glm::normalize(n) - glm::normalize(l);
        glm::vec3 v = glm::normalize(first_ray.direction);
        v *= -1;
        if (glm::dot(r, v) > 0) {
            double m = hit_obj->getMaterial().getM();
            Color ks = hit_obj->getMaterial().getKS();
            specular_light = ks * pow(glm::dot(r, v), m);
        } else {
            specular_light = Color(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        }
    } else {

        diffuse_light = Color(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        specular_light = Color(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }
    final_color += diffuse_light + specular_light;
} 
Color Ia = lights_[0].getLA();
Color ka = hit_obj->getMaterial().getKA();
Color ambient_light = Ia * ka;
final_color += ambient_light;

return final_color;
```

}

the scene header file:

```
#define SCENE_HPP
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <material.h>
#include <camera.h>
#include <light.h>
#include <shape.h>
#include <map>

struct Scene {

Scene();

void render() const;
void add(std::shared_ptr<Material> material);
void add(std::shared_ptr<Shape> shape);
void add(std::shared_ptr<Light> light);
void add(std::shared_ptr<Camera> camera);

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shape>> const& shapes() const;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Material>> const& materials() const;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Light>> const& lights() const;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Camera>> const& cameras() const;


void readFile(std::string file);
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Material>> getMaterials() const;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shape>> getShapes() const;
std::vector<Light> getLights() const;
//std::vector<Camera> getCamera();
Camera getCamera();
Material checkMaterialName(std::string name);


std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shape>> shapes_;
std::map<std::string, Material> materials_;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Light>> lights_;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Camera>> camera_;

unsigned width = 600; 
unsigned height = 600; 
};
#endif
```

and the renderer header:

```
#include "color.hpp"
#include "pixel.hpp"
#include "ppmwriter.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <shape.h>
#include "sdfloader.h"
#include <optional_hit.h>
#include <scene.h>

class Renderer {
public:
    Renderer(Scene const& scene, unsigned w, unsigned h, std::string const&     file);

  void render();
  void write(Pixel const& p);

  void testOutput();

  Color calculateColor(const Shape* hit_obj, glm::vec3 const& hit_point, Ray     const& prim_ray);

  bool Shadow(Ray sec_ray);

  inline std::vector<Color> const& colorbuffer() const {
   return colorbuffer_;
  }

  unsigned get_width() const;
  unsigned get_height() const;
  std::string get_filename() const;
  Scene get_scene() const;
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shape>> const& shapes() const;

 // OptionalHit intersect(Ray const& ray) const;

  //void render_scene(std::string file);      


private:
  unsigned width_;
  unsigned height_;
  std::vector<Color> colorbuffer_;
  std::string filename_;
  PpmWriter ppm_;

  Scene scene_;
  Camera camera_;

  std::vector<Light> lights_;
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shape>> shapes_;

};
```

If anyone can make any sense of this, any help is really appreciated!

Comment: I believe the first problem is in the Scene source file (which you do not show). Did you implement `Scene::getCamera()`?

Comment: what is your command line you are using to run the compile , have you included both the .cpp files renderer.cpp and scene.cpp in it and if so like  drescherjm asked have you implemented both getCamera and getShapes functions.